# Little Icon on Folders and Files

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

When I opened my computer suddenly I noticed this little icon in my folders and files, what does it mean?
[image]

Comment: The file is being shared

Answer (score 1):

That little icon means the file is being shared via the SMB protocol. SMB is a file sharing protocol that works with Windows, Mac OS and Linux with `samba`. The SMB protocol is not encrypted so it is only good for local networks.

You can disable file sharing on the file via the `Properties` menu. This works for folders as well and sharing a folder inherently shares its children, unless otherwise specified. You can disable file sharing completely from the control panel. (I don't remember the path unfortunately)